# Defining "add" function in a class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing my own code language in Python (called Bean), and I want the math functions to have the syntax:

print math.add(3+7)
==>10

print math.mul(4*8)
==>32

and so on. So far my code is:

```
bean_version = "1.0"
console = []
print "Running Bean v%s" % bean_version
#Math Function
class math(object):
    def __init__(self, add, sub, mul, div):
        self.add = add
        self.sub = sub
        self.mul = mul
        self.div = div
    def add(self):
        print self.add
math = math(1,0,0,0)
print math.add()
```

But this will return an error, saying that *TypeError: 'int' object is not callable*. I can change the "add" function to a different name and it will work, but I would like to use "add" as the name.
Thanks (This is Python 2.7.10 by the way)

Comment: The naming convention is very problematic. Add is an argument and a function

Comment: You say you want `math.Add()`, but then you're calling `math.add()`. And why doesn't the `add()` method take an argument like your examples?

Comment: `math.Add(4*8)` - what? That's not addition. What's even the point of this `math.Add` thing if you're going to use the regular `+` and `*` operators anyway?

Comment: @Barmar In classes, that's how you define a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to change the name of the add function, you can just change `self.add`. These two `add`s are conflicting with each other. You will not get any error if you run this:

```
bean_version = "1.0"
console = []
print "Running Bean v%s" % bean_version
#Math Function
class math(object):
    def __init__(self, add, sub, mul, div):
        self.adds = add
        self.sub = sub
        self.mul = mul
        self.div = div
    def add(self):
        print self.adds
math = math(1,0,0,0)
print math.add()
```

Answer (score 3):

An object can't have two properties with the same name. So if you have a property called `add` that holds a number, it can't also have a method called `add`, because methods are just properties that happen to hold functions. When you do:

```
this.add = add
```

you're replacing the method with that number. So you need to use different names.

You say you want to be able to call `math.Add()`. But the method you defined is `add`. It should be:

```
def Add():
    print this.add
```

This doesn't conflict with the `add` property that holds the number, since names are case-sensitive.